# PDE Singularity and time of shock

Tags: partial-differential-equations, singularity-theory

Given the following PDE:
$$∂p/∂t+p*∂p/∂x=0$$
$$p=p(x,t)$$
$$p(x,0)=e^{-x^2}$$

It is requested to find its solution, show that it is not well behaved by verifying what happens to $∂p/∂t$ and $∂p/∂x$ when $t*=(e)^{x_0²}/2x_0$ and to show that $t^{*}=(e/2)^{1/2}$ is the first $t^{*}$ where those derivatives will be singular - and is the moment when the shock occurs.

I found, for the solution, that $p(x,t)=(e)^{-x_0²}$  for all $(x,t)$ such that $x=xo+(e)^-{x_0²}*t$ (implicit solution). I also found, for $∂p/∂t$ and $∂p/∂x$,  $1/(t^{*}*e^{x_o²}(1-t*t^{*}))$ and $-1/t^{*}$, respectively. I then derived the $t^{*}$ and put it equal to zero to find the critical points and got the value requested, $(e/2)^{1/2}$.

**The problem**: I can't explain exactly - in good terms - why that is the point where the derivatives are **SINGULAR** and why that is the moment the *shock* occurs. I believe shock means shock of solutions, as regarding to the *blowup time.*

Comment: This is Burgers equation, I'm sure it is Evans book on PDE, possibly in the first order non linear equations section. If I remember correctly, the reason for the shock wave is the intersection of characteristic curves.